# Adding entry to Registry for startup of application

Tags: vb.net

I took the following method to make a registry key in my setup project.  When I run setup, it says

Could not write value Run to the key. Verify that you have the sufficient access to that key, or contact your support personnel. "

Please advise how to fix this. Thanks

Below I have copied the code that I took from the forum

1. After you have built your own application project, Right Click the "Solution" to "Add a New Project", of cource the project type is Setup and Deployment Project.

   2. Add the "Project Outputs" into the setup project, here, it can be the your own application,
   3. Most of important step:  Open the "Regstry" view of the setup project, then add new keys in "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE" according to the information I just mentioned.  Below the key "Run", you can add a new string value.  Then in the value's "Properties" view, enter "[TARGETDIR]YourApplicationName.exe" .
   4. Install your application using the msi file created by setup project, then restart your computer, you can see the result.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to write your registry under Current User instead of the Local Machine.
The end result is similar and you won't get an error.